# Where can I view sent sms if I use sendTextMessage function?

Tags: android

Normally, the sent sms will be listed in sent box if I use real samsung i8150 mobile (Android 2.3.6) to send sms,
I install an app with the following code to my mobile, but the sent sms don't be listed in sent box using the app. why?
How can I make the sent sms be listed in sent box Programmatically? Thanks!

```
SmsManager smsMgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
for (String toAddress : rule.receiverNumberList) {
    smsMgr.sendTextMessage(toAddress, null, myMSms.body, null, null);       
}
```

Comment: you need to store sent sms in sms db as the native app do.

Comment: Thanks! Could you show me some code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 ContentValues my_values = new ContentValues();
 values.put("address", "+123456789");//sender name
 values.put("body", "Message content");
 getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), my_values);
```

Permission to write sms

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
```

try this..

Comment: Thanks! but maybe should be getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);